# Slow down system when open nvim

Tags: neovim, autocompletion, plugin-coc

When I open neovim, system slows down. Even neovim's itself. switching between buffers take  one or two seconds. I think this is because of autocompletion system. I use Coc. When I run neovim, a process starts with name `Tabnine deep local` that uses much RAM and as I know this process is used for AutoCompletion system. of course when I deleted coc and restart neovim, this process started again. My `init.vim` plugin part:

```
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
Plug 'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim'
Plug 'lewis6991/gitsigns.nvim'
Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'do': { -> fzf#install() } }
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
Plug 'hoob3rt/lualine.nvim'
Plug 'norcalli/nvim-colorizer.lua'
Plug 'akinsho/nvim-bufferline.lua'
Plug 'preservim/nerdtree'
Plug 'tpope/vim-commentary'
Plug 'kyazdani42/nvim-web-devicons'
Plug 'tpope/vim-commentary'
Plug 'nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter', {'do': ':TSUpdate'}  " We recommend updating the parsers on update
Plug 'windwp/nvim-autopairs'
Plug 'ayu-theme/ayu-vim'
```

And this is the tabnine process in htop:
[image]
Now my question is this, how can I fasten up system with having auto completion?

*I use debian sid.*

Comment: Could it be that you used to use [`packer`](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim) as your plugin manager?

Comment: @TornaxO7 I use vim-plug.

Comment: Did you install [`cmp-tabnine`](https://github.com/tzachar/cmp-tabnine) or did you install it with coc?

Comment: @TornaxO7 I did not not install it I separately. I ran `apt list --installed | grep tabnine` and got nothing.

Comment: if you don't need `tabnine` then, I'd just remove its files: `rm -rf ~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/cmp-tabnine`

Comment: @TornaxO7 Thank you. I think the problem is solved now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that you installed [`cmp-tabnine`](https://github.com/tzachar/cmp-tabnine) somehow. If you don't need it anymore then you can just delete it with the following bash/zsh/fish (whatever shell you're using) command:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/cmp-tabnine
```

### Little note

It's strange for me, that you're saying that you haven't used `packer` yet because you have the folder `packer` in your `~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack` path which is normally in your runtimepath (see `:h packages`). Try and take a look if there are more plugins installed under `~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer` which you don't use. You can remove them then as well which should reduce your startup time depending what plugins there are.